# JQuery UI Timepicker, resetting minDateTime and maxDateTime to null after being set

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datetime, datetimepicker

I'm using a 3rd party `jQuery UI Timepicker` which can be found here in this git repository:
 [jQuery UI Timepicker](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon)

I have implemented a datetime range selector by simply having two `datetimepicker` input elements that pass their selected date as the other field's min or max datetime. It works and the min and max datetime are set, but when I erase one the fields it doesn't reset the other fields min/max time.

For example, let's say I set my `from` field to `4/23 5:00p`.  My `to` field can't be set earlier than `4/23 5:00p`.  When I delete the value from `from`, it should reset the `to`'s min time back to `12:00a` since `from` is no longer set, but it remains at `5:00p` even though the `minDateTime` function had been set to `null`.

How can I get the time to truly reset back to default after being set the first time?

```
var fromDatepickerPointer = fromValueFieldPointer.inputElement;
var toDatepickerPointer   = toValueFieldPointer.inputElement;
function fromOnCloseFunction(selectedDateTime, inst) {
  if(fromDatepickerPointer.val() != '') {
    var minTime = new Date($(this).datetimepicker('getDate').getTime());
    console.log("minTime: " + minTime);
    console.log("from SelectedDateTime: " + selectedDateTime);
    toDatepickerPointer.datetimepicker('option', 'minDateTime', minTime);
    toDatepickerPointer.datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', minTime);
  } else {
    console.log("from should be set to null but isn't");
    toDatepickerPointer.datetimepicker('option', 'minDateTime', null);
    toDatepickerPointer.datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', null);
  }
}
fromDatepickerPointer.datetimepicker('option', 'onClose', fromOnCloseFunction); 

function toOnCloseFunction(selectedDateTime, inst) {
  if(toDatepickerPointer.val() != '') {
    var maxTime = new Date($(this).datetimepicker('getDate').getTime());
    console.log("maxTime: " + maxTime);
    console.log("to SelectedDateTime: " + selectedDateTime);
    fromDatepickerPointer.datetimepicker('option', 'maxDate', maxTime);
    fromDatepickerPointer.datetimepicker('option', 'maxDateTime', maxTime);
  } else {
    console.log("to should be set to null but isn't");
    fromDatepickerPointer.datetimepicker('option', 'maxDate', null);
    fromDatepickerPointer.datetimepicker('option', 'maxDateTime', null);
  }
}
toDatepickerPointer.datetimepicker('option', 'onClose', toOnCloseFunction);
```

I honestly feel that it is a problem with the plugin itself and not my code, but I guess you can be the judge of that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to this problem.  In order to reset the min and max values. I set `maxDateTime` and `minDateTime` to `new Date('00:00:00')` instead of `null` when the field value is empty.